# How to change default datapath in MQv8

Tags: ibm-mq

I have two installation of MQ:
a. MQ v7.0.1.14 at E:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
b. MQ v8.0.0.5 at C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphereMQ_v8005

The datapath and logpath of version 8 is pointing at `E:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Qmgrs` and `[...]\log`.

Is there a way to change the datapath and logpath to some other directory? I don't see `mqs.ini` and `qm.ini` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphereMQ_v8005`.

Comment: You can set the log and data path (crtmqm -ld -md) for each of your queue managers separately, you don't need to use the defaults.

Answer (score 4):

When you have multiple installations of MQ, there is only one root location for the queue manager data. This location was set when you installed the first of your two installations and is where the `mqs.ini` file lives. The second install has no choice but to use the already present data path from the first installation.

You can change the data path for each queue manager at build time using the `-ld` and the `-md` options of the [`crtmqm`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083120_.htm) command.  The `-ld` option sets the log path and the `-md` option sets the data path.  You can see the effect of these commands reflected in the mqs.ini file.

Keep in mind there is one global location for the `mqs.ini` file that serves all installations on a host even if you change the data path on a per-queue-manager basis.

Also be aware that the data path you configure is associated with the queue manager and not the installation.  So if you migrate a queue manager from v7.0.1.x to v8.0.0.x it does not relocate the QMgr's data files to a different directory.

One last piece of advice is that it is possible to migrate a QMgr to a new location while it is down by moving the files and updating the `mqs.ini` file appropriately.  The trick on Windows is to ensure that the MQ service account retains ownership of the files and is authorized down the entire path from the root of the drive.  (Typically the `BypassTraverseChecking` AD permission is granted to the MQ service account and group to assure path permissions are not needed at every level.)
You do not see mqs.ini and qm.ini under C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphereMQ_v8005 because they are in the data path.

Comment: Many thanks Morag.
The MQ v7.0 installation is currently live in production.
Am trying to upgrade to v8005 and didnt wanted to disturb the existing installation.
Thought I will install MQ v8005 in a different directory and create a QMGR with the same name as in version 7 and keep the configuration ready. So on the go live date the down time would be very minimal and I just have to start the MQ v8 qmgr. But from what you have suggested, that's not going to work.

Comment: If I upgrade the live instance of MQ version 7 to 8 and by chance if there is an issue, how easy it would be to backout the upgrade? And is there an option to backout the upgrade? 
I hope it would be:
a. Stop all QMGRs on MQv7.0.1.14
b. Upgrade the installation to v8005
c. Start QMGRs and it would come up in 8005.
d. If there are issues, is there a way to move back to previous level, v7.0.1.14
e. I take daily backups of the components and the setmqauth configuration on the QMGR.

Thanks

Comment: Now that you have both installations side by side, you can upgrade each queue manager one at a time, just using the setmqm command and then strmqm with the new installation. You cannot back this out though, so remember to back up your queue manager if you want to reinstate it on the old version. The side by side installation means you don't have to do them all at once. You can also create another queue manager (with a different name) and test that first before upgrading any of the others, or you could switch apps over to that queue manager in a piece meal fashion.